# Raphael Ellipse Animation

Tags: javascript, raphael

In Raphael, I have an ellpise drawn:

```
var leftball = paper.ellipse(125, 120, 20, 20);
```

In my attempt in a mouseclick event, I would like the ellipse to change shape and value to:

```
leftball = paper.ellipse (125, 120, 20, 40);
```

Anyone can guide me to this?

I am able to animate something similar using paper.path by defining the values of the path as a string. However, as I tried to use the same method for ellipse, it does not work. My coding:

```
var leftball = "125, 120, 20, 20";
var myleftball = paper.ellipse(leftball).attr({fill:"black"});
```

The error on console mentioning:

```
Error: Invalid value for <ellipse> attribute cx"125, 120, 20, 20"
```

Thank you!

Comment: It looks like you may have a typo in your code, the error says **ellpise** .

Comment: Opps, but I've double checked. It's just a typo error when I manually typed the error message. I've made the edits as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to specify the individual attribute to animate, eg 'ry', as its not a path string.

Example

```
leftball.animate({ ry: 40 }, 2000);
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sdtt9wc9/1/)

Comment: Thank you! That worked :) 

What happens if I want to transform a ellipse to a rectangle? 

Do I have to use a path?

Comment: Yes, you would need to use a path for both, and have the exact same number of points in each path.